# Identifying the user after sign out for after_sign_out_path_for method in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise

For after sign in path, you can do the following:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.class == User
    if resource.sign_in_count < 2
      '/dashboard'
    else
      '/dashboard/home'
    end
  elsif resource.class == AdminUser
    I18n.locale = "en"
    '/admin/dashboard'
  else
    I18n.locale = "en"
    '/'
  end
end
```

But, how can I check if my user is a `User` or an `AdminUser` after `sign_out`?

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope == AdminUser
```

This does not work. Is there any way to check it?

Note: Although I have done a monkey patch and defined new root for admin and my problem is solved, but I want to know if there is any way to implement using `after_sign_out_path_for` method of Devise?

Answer (score 1):

Devise gives you the `current_user` after you sign in which is the logged in user. There is nothing like whether the user is admin or the general user.

So its not that you can use for.

You can use other ways to get what you want.

The one is Cancan which works well with Devise, you can define user roles.

With Cancan, you can define a column in your users table, say role, with values for each user like admin or general user. So then there will be `Ability.rb` file for Cancan and there you can define your logic.

You can use conditions -

```
if user.role? :admin
 #admin related logic
elsif user.role? :general
 #general user related logic
end
```

Comment: ok thanks... but this is what I know already. Isn't there a way in devise to check directly? (although I know the problem is session gets destroyed.)

Answer (score 1):

This will work here.

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if resource_or_scope == :user
    redirect_to ... # users path
  elsif resource_or_scope == :admin
    redirect_to .... # admins path
  end
end
```

Devise will call the method **after_sign_out_path_for** with the symbol of the class name as the parameter, hence we can check the condition based on that symbol.

Answer (score 0):

In your user model you could do something like this if you have a column for specifying the user role.

```
def admin?
  role == "admin"
end
```

then all you do is

```
def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
  if user.admin?
```